# three codes need to be combined in one single code

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have three codes as you see below , I do not konw how to combine them in one code so I can run it and print out if book "9780345917430" is in the list or not

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return author + ": " + title;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x){
        if (x instanceof Book){
            return isbn.equals(((Book) x).isbn);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and I have a list

```
List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

and I have an if statement

```
if (list.contains(new Book("9780345917430", null, null))) {
    System.out.println("Boken finns");
}
```

I was thinking to put the list under the  `public class Book {` and I wanted to put the if statement in a main method but the problem that I can not do it because of `public class Book {` as you see it involves `public` 
How to combine all these in one single code so I can run it in eclipse???
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse, or any IDE for that matter, can compile an entire project at once. Just create separate files, and run the class that has the `public static void main(String[] args) {` method.

Example:
BookExample.java

```
public class BookExample {
    private static List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (list.contains(new Book("9780345917430", null, null)) {
            System.out.println("Boken finns");
        }
    }
}
```

Book.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return author + ": " + title;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x){
        if (x instanceof Book){
            return isbn.equals(((Book) x).isbn);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hi , it looks that I have to remove `public` from `public class Book {` otherwise it will not work ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Book {

private String isbn;
private String title;
private String author;

public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
}

public String toString() {
    return author + ": " + title;
}

public boolean equals(Object x){
    if (x instanceof Book){
        return isbn.equals(((Book) x).isbn);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and one more method in same class

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
     if (list.contains(new Book("9780345917430", null, null))) {
     System.out.println("Boken finns");
   }
}
```

Comment: hi , it looks that I have to remove `public` from `public class Book {` otherwise it will not work ..thanks

Comment: no need to remove, why you are thinking to remove 'pubic' modifier?.

Comment: the code does not run if I have `public class Book { ` I think because the name of my file should be same as the name for main method ,,, in my case I have two `public class Book {`  and `public class BookEx{ ` (for the main method) ... so class name must be same as main method's name otherwise the code will confuse because it can not decide which `public class Book { `or `public class BookEx { ` is the main method to be executed .. thanks

Comment: public class name and File name should be same, And 'main' method name and class name no need to be same. And one more thing in real time projects may have 1000's of classes and in those classes most of them are public

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call it from a main function from other class like below

```
        public class classname {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            if (list.contains(new Book("9780345917430", null, null))) {
                System.out.println("Boken finns");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: hi , it looks that I have to remove `public` from `public class Book {` otherwise it will not work ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public static List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Book(String isbn, String title, String author) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return author + ": " + title;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x){
        if (x instanceof Book){
            return isbn.equals(((Book) x).isbn);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {

    if (list.contains(new Book("9780345917430", null, null))) 
    {
            System.out.println("Boken finns");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi , it looks that I have to remove `public` from `public class Book {` otherwise it will not work ..thanks